# Why Spark uses ordered schema for dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I wondered why spark uses ordered schema in dataframe rather than using name based schema where 2 schemas considered to be the same if for each column name they have the same type.

My first question is that what was the advantage of ordering columns in schema that spark orders columns? Does it make some operations on dataframe faster when we have this assumption?

And my second question is whether I can tell spark that the order of columns do not matter to me and consider two schemas to be the same if the unordered set of columns and their types are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I will see this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark dataframes are not relational databases. It saves time for certain types of processing; e.g. `union`, which will take in fact the names from the last DF. So, it's an implementation detail.

You therefore cannot state that ordering does not matter to Spark. See the union of the below:

```
val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "bat", "done"),
  (2, "mouse", "mone"),
  (3, "horse", "gun"),
  (4, "horse", "some")
).toDF("id", "animal", "talk")

val df = Seq(
  (1, "bat", "done"),
  (2, "mouse", "mone"),
  (3, "horse", "gun"),
  (4, "horse", "some")
).toDF("id", "talk", "animal")

val df3 = df.union(df2)
```

Note that with JSON schema inference everything is alphabetical. That to me is very handy.